# How to copy object list to another [Typescript]

Tags: angular, typescript-typings

I just want to copy value from "all" to "available" and I can't get value from available sometimes all too.

I have try many ways such as `slice()`, `Array.from()` and `=` but it's not work

```
let a = [{"key":66,"value":"MAAA","username":"MAZA007"},{"key":66,"value":"MAAA","username":"MAZA007"}];

let all = a
let available = all
```

Just no value in my variable

This is my full function

```
          protected  async processMoverBox(projectId?:number) {


            let available;
            let all;

            if(projectId != undefined)    
            {

                let projectTeamId =  await this.restful.get("api/operation/S200100/allprojectteam/"+projectId); 
                    console.log(projectTeamId)

                     all = projectTeamId.map((id) => {return this.copy(this.allUser.find(allUser => allUser.key == id))})

            }  
            else{ all = this.copy(this.allUser); console.log(this.allUser)}
            console.log(all);

            let a = [{"key":66,"value":"MAAA","username":"MAZA007"},{"key":66,"value":"MAAA","username":"MAZA007"}]


            available = [...a];

            console.log(available);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(available, null, 4));

            if(this.selected.length>0){
            this.selected.forEach((ms)=>{
                available.splice(available.findIndex(e => e.key == ms.key), 1);
            })
             }

             console.log(available);
             console.log(this.selected)

            this.memberDualbox.initMoveBox(available, this.selected, all)
            this.memberDualbox.disabled = this.isViewMode;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more code because this is working fine and does what you ask for.

Comment: `let available = all.slice(0)` should work

Comment: Not sur to understand what you want to achieve. Can you add more information please ?

Comment: Sorry for my little information. And Thank you for attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working.

However, your code isn't "copying" the data from the array assigned to variable "a". What you are doing is creating additional variables "all" and "available" that all point to the same array in memory via reference value. An array is a reference value type. If you want to create a brand new copy/clone of the array then there are various techniques. As per @uminder above you can create a shallow copy using slice.

```
let available = all.slice(0);
```

Or you could use spread syntax:

```
let available = [...all];
```

Full example:

```
(function() {

    const a = [{
        "key": 66,
        "value": "MAAA",
        "username": "MAZA007"
    }, {
        "key": 66,
        "value": "MAAA",
        "username": "MAZA007"
    }];

    const all = a;

    //Returns true (same reference)
    console.log(all === a);

    const available = [...all];

    //Returns false (new reference)
    console.log(available === a);

    //Alterntive syntax example shallow copy
    //let available = all.slice(0);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(available, null, 4));
}
)();
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer its helping me so much.

Answer (score 5):

You can assign value like the bellow example.

```
let a = [{"key":66,"value":"MAAA","username":"MAZA007"},{"key":66,"value":"MAAA","username":"MAZA007"}];

let all = a
let available = Object.assign({}, all);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need create copy arrays, you can do :
let all = a.map(val => val);
all get clone array, but array 'a' dont changed;

also may use .concat() method;

Answer (score 1):

```
if(this.selected.length>0){
  this.selected.forEach((ms)=>{
    available.splice(available.findIndex(e => e.key == ms.key), 1);
  })
}
```

Why not

```
const available = all.filter(e => this.selected.some(ms => e.key === m.key));
```