# Typescript: Copy Type List into another Type List with similar members

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In Typescript, I want to take an ArrayList of ProcedureCode, and copy all the contents into ArrayList of ProcedureView. This will keep the similar members, while have null values temporarily for 2 new members in ProcedureView. Whats an easy way to do this? researching answers with spread operator , and following https://stackoverflow.com/a/57109024/15435022

```
export type ProcedureCode = {
  code: string;
  officialName: string;
  localName: string;
  active: boolean;
};

export type ProcedureView = ProcedureCode & {
  inventory: number;
  itemDescription: string;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am thinking about this implementations

```
export type ProcedureCode = {
  code: string;
  officialName: string;
  localName: string;
  active: boolean;
};

export type ProcedureView = ProcedureCode & {
  inventory: number | null;
  itemDescription: string | null;
};

const procedureCodes: ProcedureCode[] = [
  {
    code: "code",
    officialName: "official name",
    localName: "local name",
    active: false
  },
  {
    code: "code 2",
    officialName: "official name 2",
    localName: "local name 2",
    active: false
  }
];

const procedureViews: ProcedureView[] = procedureCodes.map((procedureCode) => {
  const procedureView = {
    ...procedureCode,
    inventory: null,
    itemDescription: null
  };

  return procedureView;
});
```

Comment: thanks, can we apply some of these answers to simplify it? appreciate it, just reading this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441682/how-to-copy-matching-properties-from-one-object-to-another

Comment: you can replace procedureView with this to achieve that like this 
`const procedureView = Object.assign({}, procedureCode, {
  inventory: null,
  itemDescription: null
});`
but i prefer use object spread operator

Comment: what if there are 25 plus additional fields , instead of 2,  is there a simple code, without typing null for each? thanks

Comment: then u should use some design pattern like `BuilderPattern`